# Best way to add icon to delphi 2007 app (win7)

Tags: delphi, windows-7, icons, delphi-2007

I want to add icon to my delphi app. Icon was generated from image via ICOFX, including 128x128 and 256x256 (Vista) icons. I tried to add icon several times:

First of all, using Code Gear IDE: `Project Options->Application->Icon`. This was an easy way, but Vista-sized icons (128x128 and 256x256) were not added. When scaling in Windows Explorer `Ctrl+Wheel`, icon stoped increasing in size after 64x64. This happens because Delphi does not support big icons.

Then I tried to change icon in MyProject.RES file (using ResourseExplorer). It did not helped much.

When changing .exe-file icon using ResourseExplorer problems seems to be solved, but this is not a Path of a jedi, obviously. And some problems appears/remains, such as:

1. when changing .exe-file name (ex: from MEPROG.EXE to _MYPROG.EXE), file icon is changing either (128x128 and 256x256 icons disappeare).
2. when using `MouseRightButton->Send to->Desktop` to create a label, label's icon is of small resolution.
3. copy-pasting exe-file into some other directory(not in deplhi project output dir), could also change icon.

Is there a better way to do this, or I am doing this wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the change-log around 2.7 version

http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/

it seems you just try to use Delphi without installing necessary fixes

*PS. another way might be to make some command-line utility replacing icon resource and then auto-call it after compilation phase. Still ugly, but better than manually launchign ResEdit each time.*

Comment: Why would command line tools to perform build actions be ugly? Surely it's the exact opposite. IDE Fix Pack is essential mind you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ugly is not CLI. Ugly is the approach when instead of making the compiler do the proper thing we instead would introduce after-the-fact patching.

Comment: The IDE's handling of the application resource is opaque to version control. So I always take that under my own control so that I can keep the app icon, manifest generation, version info, etc. subject to revision control and transparent. That's my personal feeling. Of course there are lots of ways to skin this. I certainly agree that after-the-fact patching of compiled resources is ugly. But automating creation of .rc file and compilation to .res is good.

Answer (score 4):

The Delphi 2007 IDE cannot handle large Vista icons, which use PNG compression. And neither can the `brcc32` resource compiler that ships with Delphi 2007.

My solution, when I was still using legacy Delphi versions, was to make a .rc file containing the icons, and compile using the MS resource compiler, `rc`. The MS resource compiler does support such icons, and is readily available, for example with the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see the icon, you can just run the following command to clear the icon cache:

`ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache`

For Windows 10, use:

`ie4uinit.exe -show`